# git bundle with symbolic ref

Tags: git, git-rev-list, git-bundle

I'm trying to share our git repo with an offsite development team. We do not have a "master" branch. We have A/master, B/master, and C/master. I have a symbolic ref in my pub repo

> HEAD -> refs/heads/B/master

When I create the bundle `git bundle create my.bundle --remotes --tags` I end up with two references to refs/remotes/origin/B/master and that causes `git clone --mirror my.bundle` to fail. Is there a way to ignore the symbolic ref?

Comment: The simplest would be to use `git rev-parse` to turn `--remotes` into the actual full names (`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --remotes`), then filter the list down. (You can include `--tags` in the rev-parse set, if you like, making them available for filtering too, or pass `--tags` directly to `git bundle` as before.)

Comment:  Thanks! I used '`'` instead of '(' to execute the rev-parse. If you post it as a solution I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use:

```
git bundle create my.bundle \
    $(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --remotes --tags | grep -v HEAD)
```

or something along these lines.  (The line break with backslash is mostly for posting purposes, and watch out for this removing too many `HEAD` entries, e.g., if you have a remote-tracking name or tag name like `getAHEADofit`.)